# Build Error whenever I add Microsoft.EntityframeworkCore.SqlServer

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Using .NET Core 3.0 latest preview, I created a project as follows:

```
"ASP.NET Core Web Application" -> "Blazor (ASP.NET Core hosted)"
```

Which creates a Solution with 3 projects: Client, Server, and Shared.

Once I add `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlserver` ver. `2.2.4` (latest) or any other driver (e.g. `Sqlite`) to the Shared project, and build the solution, I get the following ONE error:

> The command "dotnet "C:\Users\Walad.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.mono\0.10.0-preview-20190325.1\build\netstandard1.0../../tools/illink/illink.dll" -l none --verbose --strip-security true --exclude-feature com --exclude-feature sre -v false -c link -u link -b true -d "C:\Users\Walad.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.mono\0.10.0-preview-20190325.1\build\netstandard1.0../../tools/mono/bcl/" -d "C:\Users\Walad.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.mono\0.10.0-preview-20190325.1\build\netstandard1.0../../tools/mono/bcl/Facades/" -o "D:\Family_Data\Said_Data\Desktop\My Desktop\Temp\Blazor10.Client\obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\blazor\linker/" -x "C:\Users\Walad.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.build\3.0.0-preview4-19216-03\targets\BuiltInBclLinkerDescriptor.xml" -x "D:\Family_Data\Said_Data\Desktop\My Desktop\Temp\Blazor10.Client\obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\blazor\linker.descriptor.xml" -a "C:\Users\Walad.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor\3.0.0-preview4-19216-03\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.dll" -a "C:\Users\Walad.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.components\3.0.0-preview4-19216-03\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.dll" -a "C:\Users\Walad.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.components.browser\3.0.0-preview4-19216-03\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Browser.dll" -a "C:\Users\Walad.nuget\packages\microsoft.entityframeworkcore\2.2.4\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll" -a "C:\Users\Walad.nuget\packages\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.abstractions\2.2.4\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions.dll" -a "C:\Users\Walad.nuget\packages\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relational\2.2.4\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll" -a "C:\Users\Walad.nuget\packages\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserver\2.2.4\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.dll" -a "C:\Users\Walad.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.caching.abstractions\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions.dll" -a "C:\Users\Walad.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.caching.memory\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.dll" -a "C:\Users\Walad.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.configuration\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll" -a "C:\Users\Walad.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.configuration.abstractions\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll" -a "C:\Users\Walad.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.configuration.binder\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder.dll" -a "C:\Users\Walad.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection\3.0.0-preview4.19216.2\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll" -a "C:\Users\Walad.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.abstractions\3.0.0-preview4.19216.2\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll" -a "C:\Users\Walad.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.logging\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll" -a "C:\Users\Walad.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.logging.abstractions\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll" -a "C:\Users\Walad.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.options\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll" -a "C:\Users\Walad.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.primitives\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll" -a "C:\Users\Walad.nuget\packages\microsoft.jsinterop\3.0.0-preview4.19216.2\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.JSInterop.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.win32.registry\4.5.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll" -a "C:\Users\Walad.nuget\packages\mono.webassembly.interop\3.0.0-preview4.19216.2\lib\netstandard2.0\Mono.WebAssembly.Interop.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\remotion.linq\2.2.0\lib\netstandard1.0\Remotion.Linq.dll" -a "C:\Users\Walad.nuget\packages\system.buffers\4.4.0\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Buffers.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.collections.immutable\1.5.0\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Collections.Immutable.dll" -a "C:\Users\Walad.nuget\packages\system.componentmodel.annotations\4.6.0-preview4.19212.13\lib\netstandard2.0\System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll" -a "C:\Users\Walad.nuget\packages\system.data.sqlclient\4.6.0\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Data.SqlClient.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.diagnostics.diagnosticsource\4.5.0\lib\netstandard1.3\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll" -a "C:\Users\Walad.nuget\packages\system.interactive.async\3.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Interactive.Async.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.linq\4.1.0\lib\netstandard1.6\System.Linq.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.linq.expressions\4.1.0\lib\netstandard1.6\System.Linq.Expressions.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.linq.queryable\4.0.1\lib\netstandard1.3\System.Linq.Queryable.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.memory\4.5.1\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Memory.dll" -a "C:\Users\Walad.nuget\packages\system.numerics.vectors\4.4.0\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.objectmodel\4.0.12\lib\netstandard1.3\System.ObjectModel.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.reflection.emit\4.0.1\lib\netstandard1.3\System.Reflection.Emit.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.reflection.emit.ilgeneration\4.0.1\lib\netstandard1.3\System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.reflection.emit.lightweight\4.0.1\lib\netstandard1.3\System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.reflection.typeextensions\4.1.0\lib\netstandard1.5\System.Reflection.TypeExtensions.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe\4.5.1\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.security.accesscontrol\4.5.0\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Security.AccessControl.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.security.principal.windows\4.5.0\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.text.encoding.codepages\4.5.0\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Text.Encoding.CodePages.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.threading\4.0.11\lib\netstandard1.3\System.Threading.dll" -a "D:\Family_Data\Said_Data\Desktop\My Desktop\Temp\Blazor10.Shared\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\Blazor10.Shared.dll" -a "D:\Family_Data\Said_Data\Desktop\My Desktop\Temp\Blazor10.Client\obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\Blazor10.Client.dll"" exited with code -532462766.

Comment: Why don't you take the matching 3.0.0 preview of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlserver`?

Comment: YES! I just realized that when I used the EF Core 3.0 Preview 4, which was just announced yesterday in here:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-entity-framework-core-3-0-preview-4/

The problem was solved!!!

I installed the preview version of EF using the command line.

Is there a way to make Preview Packages appear in the NuGet Manager so that I can select and install?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/prerelease-packages

Comment: Gottcha -- Love you guys!